# Open a file in wordpad using python

Tags: ms-word, wordpad

Is there a way to open a word file using wordpad (not MS word)? I can use win32com.client to open doc file using MS word like this:

```
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    word.Visible = True
```

Not sure how to do this using wordpad. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I could get this working using subprocess:

```
    import subprocess as sp
    sp.Popen([programName, fileName])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pf = os.getenv("ProgramFiles")
subprocess.call([pf + "\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe",filename])
```